# VTD fails to evaluate a "find all empty nodes with no attributes" xpath

Tags: xpath, vtd-xml

I found a bug (I think) using the 2.13.4 version of vtd-xml. Well, in short I have the following snippet code:

```
String test = "<catalog><description></description></catalog>";
VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
vg.setDoc(test.getBytes("UTF-8"));
vg.parse(true);
VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
//get nodes with no childs, text and attributes
String xpath = "/catalog//*[not(child::node()) and not(child::text()) and count(@*)=0]";
AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
ap.selectXPath(xpath);
//block inside while is never executed
 while(ap.evalXPath()!=-1) {
   System.out.println("current node "+vn.toRawString(vn.getCurrentIndex()));
}
```

and this doesn't work (=do not find any node, while it should find "description" instead). The code above works if I use the self closed tag:

```
String test = "<catalog><description/></catalog>";
```

The point is every xpath evaluator works with both version of the xml. Sadly I receive the xml from an external source, so I have no power over it... 
Breaking the xpath I noticed that evaluating both

```
/catalog//*[not(child::node())]
```

and

```
/catalog//*[not(child::text())]
```

give false as result. As additional bit I tried something like:

```
String xpath = "/catalog/description/text()";
ap.selectXpath(xpath);
if(ap.evalXPath()!=-1)
   System.out.println(vn.toRawString(vn.getCurrentIndex()));
```

And this print empty space, so in some way VTD "thinks" the node has text, even empty but still, while I expect a no match. Any hint?

Comment: does this bug exist for prior version of vtd-xml?

Comment: @vtd-xml-author it exists in 2.11 and 2.12 as well (didn't try other minor versions btw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

> When I faced this issue, I was left mainly with three options (see below). I went for the second option : Use XMLModifier to fix the VTDNav. At the bottom of my answser, you'll find an implementation of this option and a sample output.

---

### The long story ...

I faced the same issue. Here are the main three options I first thought of (by order of difficulty) :

#### 1. Turn empty elements into self closed tags in the XML source.

*This option isn't always possible (like in OP case). Moreover, it may be difficult to "pre-process" the xml before hand.*

#### 2. Use [XMLModifier](https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/javadoc/com/ximpleware/XMLModifier.html) to fix the [VTDNav](https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/javadoc/com/ximpleware/VTDNav.html).

*Find the empty elements with an xpath expression, replace them with self closed tags and rebuild the VTDNav.*

#### 2.bis Use [XMLModifier#removeToken](https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/javadoc/com/ximpleware/XMLModifier.html#removeToken-int-)

*A lower level variant of the preceding solution would consist in looping over the tokens in VTDNav and remove unecessary tokens thanks to [XMLModifier#removeToken](https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io/javadoc/com/ximpleware/XMLModifier.html#removeToken-int-).*

#### 3. Patch the vtd-xml code directly.

*Taking this path may require more effort and more time. IMO, the optimized vtd-xml code isn't easy to grasp at first sight.*

---

Option 1 wasn't feasible in my case. I failed implementing Option 2bis. The "unecessary" tokens still remained. I didn't look at Option 3 because I didn't want to fix some (rather complex) third party code.

I was left with Option 2. Here is an implementation:

#### Code

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.NavException;
import com.ximpleware.VTDException;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;
import com.ximpleware.XMLModifier;

@Test
public void turnEmptyElementsIntoSelfClosedTags() throws VTDException, IOException {
    // STEP 1 : Load XML into VTDNav
    // * Convert the initial xml code into a byte array
    String xml = "<root><empty-element></empty-element><self-closed/><empty-element2 foo='bar'></empty-element2></root>";
    byte[] ba = xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // * Build VTDNav and dump it to screen
    VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
    vg.setDoc(ba);
    vg.parse(false); // Use `true' to activate namespace support

    VTDNav nav = vg.getNav();
    dump("BEFORE", nav);


    // STEP 2 : Prepare to fix the VTDNAv
    // * Prepare an autopilot to find empty elements
    AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(nav);
    ap.selectXPath("//*[count(child::node())=1][text()='']");

    // * Prepare a simple regex matcher to create self closed tags
    Matcher elementReducer = Pattern.compile("^<(.+)></.+>$").matcher("");


    // STEP 3 : Fix the VTDNAv
    // * Instanciate an XMLModifier on the VTDNav
    XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(nav);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // baos will hold the elements to fix
    String utf8 = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();

    // * Find all empty elements and replace them
    while (ap.evalXPath() != -1) {
        nav.dumpFragment(baos);
        String emptyElementXml = baos.toString(utf8);
        String selfClosingTagXml = elementReducer.reset(emptyElementXml).replaceFirst("<$1/>");

        xm.remove();
        xm.insertAfterElement(selfClosingTagXml);

        baos.reset();
    }

    // * Rebuild VTDNav and dump it to screen
    nav = xm.outputAndReparse(); // You MUST call this method to save all your changes
    dump("AFTER", nav);
}

private void dump(String msg,VTDNav nav) throws NavException, IOException {
    System.out.print(msg + ":\n  ");
    nav.dumpFragment(System.out);
    System.out.print("\n\n");
}
```

#### Output

```
BEFORE:
  <root><empty-element></empty-element><self-closed/><empty-element2 foo='bar'></empty-element2></root>

AFTER:
  <root><empty-element/><self-closed/><empty-element2 foo='bar'/></root>
```